# Using gcc documentation

Tags: documentation, gcc

I downloaded gcc-4.1-doc package to my Ubuntu computer. How can I use it? What command should I execute to see this documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man gcc` should do the trick.
`/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.1/` also contains docs.

Here's the list of files that are installed:
`
/usr/share/doc-base/gcc-4.1

/usr/share/doc-base/gccint-4.1

/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.1-base/gcc.html

/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.1-base/gccint.html

/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.1-doc

/usr/share/info/gcc-4.1.info.gz

/usr/share/info/gccint-4.1.info.gz
`

So you can use the `info` program to read the docs as well.

Comment: Thank you, got it working. I see that this is language specification and command line reference. What about CRT functions? For example, I want to type "sqrt" and see its definition, required h-file and library where this function is placed.

Comment: try `apropos sqrt`.

Output:

csqrt (3)            - complex square root
csqrtf (3)           - complex square root
csqrtl (3)           - complex square root
sqrt (3)             - square root function
sqrtf (3)            - square root function
sqrtl (3)            - square root function

If you do not get the required output you should try installing `libc6-dev`

Answer (score 4):

Running `man gcc` is likely to give you an abbreviated manual page.

Usually (most systems - I'm not certain of Ubuntu specifically) you get more information from:

```
info gcc
```

You might need to specify where `info` is to look for the documentation; add options such as:

```
info -d /usr/gcc/v4.1 -f gcc.info gcc
```

You might need to specify a sub-directory like `/usr/gcc/v4.1/share/info` rather than the configured prefix directory.

Answer (score 2):

gcc's man page is only good for an overview of the command line options. The real documentation is in info format.

You can use the 'info' program to view the full documentation : 'info gcc'. If you are an emacs user, you can use it's info mode also (M-x info to get there).

The gcc-*-doc packages also include html formated versions of the info docs. You can point your web browser to file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.1-base/ to find it.